# How to send email verification using Laravel and React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel

I want to send the user a verification email after they have created their profile. I am using axios and Sanctum to handle the user registration.

In my AuthController.php file I have

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request){
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'name' => 'required|max:40',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:200|unique:users,email',
        'password' => 'required|min:8',

    ]);
    if($validator->fails()){
        return response()->json(['validation_errors'=>messages()]);
    }
    else{
        $user = User::create([
            'name'=> $request->name,
            'email'=> $request->email,
            'password'=> Hash::make($request->password),
        ]);
        $token = $user->createToken($user->email.'_Token')->plainTextToken;
        return response()->json([
            'status'=>200,
            'username'=>$user->name,
            'token'=>$token,
            'message'=>'Registration Successful',
        ])->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    }
}
```

and in the Register.jsx file I have

`

```
export default function Register() {
const navigate = useNavigate();
const [registerInput, setRegister] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    error_list: [],
})
const handleInput = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    setRegister({...registerInput, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
}

const registerSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const data = {
        name: registerInput.name,
        email: registerInput.email,
        password: registerInput.password,
    }

    axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
        axios.post(`http://localhost:8000/api/register`, data).then(res => { 
            if(res.data.status === 200)
            {
                localStorage.setItem('auth_token', res.data.token);
                localStorage.setItem('auth_name', res.data.username);
                swal("Success",res.data.message,"success");
                navigate('/login');
            }
            else
            {
                setRegister({...registerInput, error_list: res.data.validation_errors});
            }
        });
    });
  }


}
```

This method works and I can create new users in the table. The thing is I want to authenticate the created user because the project might get filled with bots.

Answer (score 0):

If you want integrate your project email verification:

- First you need email or smtp creditionals,
- after successfully creating user you should response about need verification message to frontend in your case react (not login page).
  After that there are  different ways todo verification proccess. Easy way is generateing unique link for verification and send them user email and when entering this url you can set user active after that send user to login page for sign in to account.
  Example implement:
  https://codeanddeploy.com/blog/laravel/how-to-implement-laravel-8-email-verification